# Как выбрать 2 первых столбца?

Tags: mysql, php, sql

В общем, у меня много listbox-сов, куда нужно подгружать списки с разных таблиц, я сделал
функцию:

```
public function getValueList($table)
{
        $stmt = $this->link->prepare("SELECT 1,2 FROM $table");
        $stmt->execute();
        return $this->returnData($stmt);
}
```

Но таблицы разные, соответственно и первые 2 столбца имею разные имена, как мне выбрать именно 2 первых столбца? Думал **SELECT 1,2 FROM ...**, но нет. Подскажите, если знаете, спасибо.

Comment: @Юра Сучко, если грубо, то последовательность столбцов в SQL вещь номинальная. Вы уверены, что вам всегда будет приходить то, что нужно, а не надо их все-таки подставлять каждый раз?

> Конкретнее, рассматриваемая таблица должна удовлетворять следующим пяти условиям:
> ...
> 2.Нет упорядочивания столбцов слева-направо (другими словами, порядок столбцов не несет в себе никакой информации).

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: @Etki вообще, в mysql порядок столбцов в ответе фиксирован схемой, или запросом. Иначе выражение `INSERT INTO TABLENAME VALUES(1,2,3);` никогда бы не работало предсказуемо.

Comment: @eicto, ай ноу, селект всегда всё возвращает в том же порядке, в котором было задано при создании таблицы, да и поля можно вставлять в конкретную позицию при добавлении после создания таблицы. Конкретно второе предложение про то, что рано или поздно @Юра Сучко столкнется с тем, что title у него лежит третьим полем. Чего сразу можно избежать, если действовать, считая, что никакого порядка столбцов нет и в помине.

Comment: Это естественно, просто на самом деле интересно было бы посмотреть на работающее решение, да еще и одним запросом без процедуры, я чет ленив, но понятно что надо через information schema как-то делать, но как сделать чтобы это было бы хотя-бы вложенным запросом а не переменной в той же транзакции чето не соображу.

Comment: Да, я понял, лучше вручную, лишний параметр буду передавать, зато буду уверен, что смена порядка ничего не испортит, спасибо.